# How to remove an elements active state when a sub element is clicked

Tags: html, css

I'm currently testing html list using bootstrap and some of my own custom css items. For the last day I have been stuck on how to remove a parents `:active` state when a sub link is clicked with its own `:active` state.

Below is a like to my code, I have tried changing `z-index`, and also tried removing it with jquery with no luck.

My main goal is to keep the list items hover state but once the setting icon is click the item go back to normal view.

Any help would be great.

[My Current Code on CodePen](http://codepen.io/zacharyshupp/pen/XNOZoB?editors=1111)

```css
    .genericItem, .item img, .item .item-description, .item .item-settings {
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: middle;
    }

    /*List-group*/
    .list-group-item:hover,
    .list-group-item:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: whitesmoke;
    }

    .list-group-item:active {
      background-color: #2980b9;
      Color: white;
    }

    /*Items*/
    .item {
      -webkit-user-select: none;
    }
    .item .item-description {
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    .item .item-description p {
       margin-top: -4px;
    }
    .item .item-settings {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      float: right;
    }
    .item .item-settings:hover, .item .item-settings:focus {
      color: red;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .item .item-settings:active {
       color: green;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .item .item-settings:visited {
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item item">   
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/files-color/104/46-files-console-32.png" alt="" />
      <div class="item-description">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Dev Console</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"><i>Powershell Console, No Profile Loaded</i></p>
      </div>
      <a class="fa fa-cog item-settings" aria-hidden="true"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item item">   
      <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miscellaneous-4/32/toolbox-32.png" alt="" />
      <div class="item-description">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Computer Management</h4>
      </div>
      <a class="fa fa-cog item-settings" aria-hidden="true"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to use javascript. CSS3 doesn't support styling of parent element

Comment: Try using using the HTML DOM addEventListener() method. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) is a quick guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your structure of use javascript

here is an example of how I would change the structure

HTML

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div class=" item">
      <div class="list-group-item">
        <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/files-color/104/46-files-console-32.png" alt="" />
        <div class="item-description">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Dev Console</h4>
          <p class="list-group-item-text"><i>Powershell Console, No Profile Loaded</i></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="fa fa-cog item-settings" aria-hidden="true"></a>
    </div>
    <div class=" item">
      <div class="list-group-item item">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miscellaneous-4/32/toolbox-32.png" alt="" />
        <div class="item-description">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Computer Management</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="fa fa-cog item-settings" aria-hidden="true"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
/*List-group*/

.item > div:hover,
.item > div:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}

.item > div:active {
  background-color: rgb(41, 128, 185);
  Color: white;
}

.item{
  position: relative;
}

.item > a{
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBXGQy?editors=1111

Comment: Thank you so much, such a simple change.

Comment: Glad I could help.